# How should AngularJS handle 403 error in $http.post due to outdated XSRF token?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An AngularJS version 1.4.8 app is getting an unhandled `403` error when its login form sends data to a backend REST authentication service after the user's browser has been left open for many (16 in this case) hours.  Upon deeper analysis, the root cause is that the client AngularJS app has outdated cookies for `XSRF-TOKEN` and `JSESSIONID`, which causes the backend Spring Security to reject the request to the public `/login1` service because Spring thinks the request is cross site request forgery.

The problem can be resolved manually if the user closes all browser windows and then re-opens a new browser window before making the request again.  But this is not an acceptable user experience.  I have read [the AngularJS documentation at this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), and I see that I can add an `errorCallback` function, but how specifically should i re-write the function to handle the `403` error?

Here is the original `this.logForm()` method in the authorization service, which you can see does not handle `403` errors:

```
this.logForm = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
        var usercredentials = {type:"resultmessage", name: this.credentials.username, encpwd: this.credentials.password };
        $http.post('/login1', usercredentials)
            .then(
                function(response, $cookies) {              
                    if(response.data.content=='login1success'){// do some stuff
                    } else {// do other stuff
                    }
                }
            );
    }
};
```

Here is my very rough attempt at a revised version of the `this.logForm()` method attempting to handle a `403` error following the example in the AngularJS documentation:

```
this.logForm = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
        var usercredentials = {type:"resultmessage", name: this.credentials.username, encpwd: this.credentials.password };
        $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/login1', usercredentials })
            .then(
                function successCallback(response, $cookies) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
                    if(response.data.content=='login1success'){// do some stuff
                    } else {// do other stuff
                    }
                }, 
                function errorCallback(response, status) {// is status a valid parameter to place here to get the error code?
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
                    if(status == 403){
                        this.clearCookies();
                        // try to call this POST method again, but how?  And how avoid infinite loop?
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
```

**What specific changes need to be made to the code above to handle the 403 error due to server-perceived XSRF-TOKEN and JSESSIONID issues?  And how can the post be called a second time after deleting the cookies without leading to an infinite loop in the case where deleting the cookies does not resolve the 403 error?**

I am also looking into global approaches to error handling, but there is a combination of public and secure backend REST services, which would need to be handled separately, leading to complexity.  This login form is the first point of user entry, and I want to handle it separately before looking at global approaches which would retain a separate handling of the login form using methods developed in reply to this OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [angular-http-auth module](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) and how things are done there. I think one key element you would want to use is a [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
> synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
> postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
> requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
> they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
> requests. The interceptors leverage the promise APIs to fulfill this
> need for both synchronous and asynchronous pre-processing.

After playing around with interceptors you can look at the angular-http-auth http buffer and [the way they handle rejected requests](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/master/src/http-auth-interceptor.js#L59) there. If their interceptor receives a `responseError`, they add the [`config` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) - which basically stores all information about your request - to a buffer, and then any time they want they can manipulate elements in that buffer. You could easily adept their code to manipulate the config's xsrfHeaderName, xsrfCookieName, or parameters on your behalf when you receive a 403.

Comment: Show code.  The OP asks for code.  As it stands, your response is nothing more than a couple of comments.  By placing your comments where an answer should go, you inhibit others from replying with REAL answers.

Comment: Links can change.  The standard practice on this site is to include relevant code in the answer, and then to post a link to give credit to whoever wrote the code originally.  Simply posting a link without adding the code here makes this answer useless to anyone else who finds this in the future, after the link has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your http calls to auto retry, and use promises in your controllers (or whatever)

```
  var httpPostRetry = function(url, usercredentials) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var retries = 0;
    var postRetry = function(url, usercredentials) {
      if (retries < 3) {
       $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/login1', usercredentials })
        .then(function(result) {
          resolve(result);
        }).catch(function(result) {
          retries ++;
          postRetry(url, usercredentials);
        });
      } else {
        reject(result);
      }
    };

  }.bind(this));
  return promise;
}
```

and then you would call

```
httpPostRetry(bla, bla).then(function(result) {
  // one of the 3 tries must of succeeded
}).catch(function(result) {
  // tried 3 times and failed each time
});
```

To handle specific http errors you can broadcast that specific error and handle that case in a specific controller. Or use a service to encapsulate the status and have some other part of your code handle the UI flow for that error.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized http error', { somedata: {} });
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you.  This sounds promising... Where would your code go in relation to the `this.logForm = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) { ...}` that is needs to handle the form data?  If I could see how to fit your code suggestions into the form handler, it would make a lot more sense.